# How to transform "Tags Values" in Telegraf

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

**How can I transform the Tag Values in Telegraf?**

I am trying to import Web access logs into InfluxDB with Telegraf. However, some of the URL PATHs include identifiers *(session IDs, product IDs, etc)*.

I need to search and aggregate per path type *(ids excluded)*, therefore, I can't(?) have them vary like that.

---

In the input plugin "[logparser](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/logparser)" I can use a grok extraction pattern but I can't do transformations of the values extracted that I know of.

And the only processor plugin *(in between Input and Output)* is merely a "[printer](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/processors/printer)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any clean way of doing this with Telegraf. Maybe I could do some gymmics with Telegraf *(multiple Grok parsers + ex/inclusions?)* but after some quite extensive attempts I didn't manage to make anything work - it appeared quite fiddly.

This is only half an answer but:

I managed to achieve what I was trying with LogStash instead, outputting to InfluxDB (LogStash has its own output plugin to InfluxDB). Not as desirable, since now I'm having to run both Telegraf + LogStash but it's working.

I've created a feature request on Telegraf's GitHub:
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/2667